# Java NIO: When to properly switch between OP_WRITE and OP_READ

Tags: java, sockets, nio

As some background:

I have a connection to a server with a SocketChannel, SelectionKey...etc. On the client end, if I want to send something to the server, I just write my data into a ByteBuffer and send it through the socket channel. If all of it was written, I'm done and can return to OP_READ. If not all of it was written, I take the bytes left over, store them in a "to send" buffer somewhere and mark OP_WRITE on the key (is it a good idea to replace OP_READ so its only write?).

Therefore, the next time I call selectNow(), I'm assuming it will recognize OP_WRITE and attempt to flush more data through (which I will attempt to do by entering another writing loop with the data to write, and repeating the previous if needed).

This leads me to two questions:

- Am I supposed to leave it in OP_WRITE until all the data has been flushed through? Or should I change to OP_READ and attempt any reads in between?

If the writing channel is full and I can't write, do I just keep looping until I can start writing stuff through? If the connection suddenly gets choked, I'm unsure if I'm supposed to just write what I can, flip back to OP_READ, attempt to read, then flip back to OP_WRITE. From what I've read, this appears to not be the correct way to do things (and may cause large overhead constantly switching back and forth?).

- What is the optimal way to handle reading and writing bulk data when the buffers both may become full?

Reading sounds easy cause you just loop through until the data is consumed, but with writing... the server may be only writing and not reading. This would leave you with quite a full send buffer, and cycling around forever on OP_WRITE without reading would be bad. How do you avoid that situation? Do you set a timer on which you just stop attempting to write and start reading again if the send buffer is not clearing up? If so, do you remove OP_WRITE and remember it for later?

Side question: Do you even need OP_READ to read from the network? I'm unsure if it's like OP_WRITE where you only mark it in a specific case (just in case I', doing it wrong, since I have it on OP_READ 99.9% of the time).

Currently I just set my key to OP_READ and then leave it in that mode, waiting for data, and then go to OP_WRITE if and only if writing fails to send all the data (with a write() value of 0).

Comment: I think I'd like to see some (simplified) code.  You mention OP_WRITE and `selectNow()`, but not `Selector`, just `SocketChannel`, so I'm really kind of confused what the heck you are doing.

Comment: @markspace How is it confusing? Selector is implied, how would you call `selectNow()` *without* a selector? Some of my stuff can be answered without even needing code since the latter half is purely conceptual.

Comment: Using a selector is complicated enough even with code.  With just an English description there's no way for me to guess what is actually going on.  If someone else wants to guess, knock yourself out, but I can't figure out what you are really trying to do/having a problem with.

Comment: @markspace It's perfectly clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am I supposed to leave it in OP_WRITE until all the data has been flushed through? Or should I change to OP_READ and attempt any reads in between?

There are differing views about that. Mine is that the peer should be reading every part of the response you're sending before he sends a new request, and if he doesn't he is just misbehaving, and this you shouldn't encourage by reading ahead. Otherwise you just run out of memory eventually, and you shouldn't let a client do that to you. Of course that assumes you're the server in a request-response protocol. Other situations have their own requirements.

> If the writing channel is full and I can't write, do I just keep looping until I can start writing stuff through?

No, you wait for OP_WRITE to fire.

> If the connection suddenly gets choked, I'm unsure if I'm supposed to just write what I can, flip back to OP_READ, attempt to read, then flip back to OP_WRITE. From what I've read, this appears to not be the correct way to do things (and may cause large overhead constantly switching back and forth?).

The overhead isn't significant, but it's the wrong thing to do in the situation I described above.

> What is the optimal way to handle reading and writing bulk data when the buffers both may become full?

In general, read when OP_READ fires; write whenever you need to; and use OP_WRITE to tell you when an outbound stall has relieved itself.

> Do you even need OP_READ to read from the network?

Yes, otherwise you just smoke the CPU.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you need to write just set interested operation to (OP_READ || OP_WRITE). When you finish writing just set the interested operation to OP_READ.

that's all you have to do.

Comment: You don't need to set OP_WRITE 'when you need to write'. You need to set it when you need to know when you *can* write, after a write has returned zero, and at no other time.